# Character searching for a blade to kill a cyborg

Tags: story-identification, movie, space, cartoon

I saw this cartoon only once, about 10-15 years ago, and since middle. There was a character called "space fly" or so – the glowing flying ball which help the main character – a man with sword hilt. Main character searching for the blade for that hilt to assemble a weapon with which he can kill the main villain who is a cyborg, but it shows (that he is a cyborg) only in the final battle in the end of the movie. Through the cartoon, main character fights with the enemies (robots whitch serves the main villain) with his sword hilt (in the moment of hit the enemy, from hilt grows red glowing blade, something like jady blade). In the final battle, main character loses his hilt, but space fly tell him, that blade never exist, and he should to believe in his own forces. After that, he can grow the glowing blade from his hands, and win.

Forgive me my broken English, but help me to find how called this cartoon. It's memories torture me more then 10 years and I must see this film=).

P.S. It's not He-man. Drawing more similiar with "Transformers: the movie" 1986, and I think cartoon was USA or USA/Japan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing [Starchaser: Legend of Orin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starchaser:_The_Legend_of_Orin).

- Main character's name is **Star Fly**
- Main character is seeking a magical sword
- Main character learns he can make the sword appear by magic.

**[JosefBeeby](http://josefbeeby.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/starchaser-legend-of-orin.html) offers the following (quite snarky) review:**

> The Star Fly shows up again to help them in wholly unnatural ways
>   suggesting some greater importance but there's no time to dwell on
>   that. He loses the hilt just in time to understand that the hidden
>   blade he was looking for was inside himself the whole time. Not
>   literally, it just means he can make lightsabers (or solar swords) by
>   holding his fists together.

Comment: Man, thank you! Very very very very very GREAT THANK!!! I was a boy when I see last half of this film, and some details in my memory are blurry. I thought "space fly" because translation from russian localization (космическая муха) more like "space".